# Program or website for transcribing Old and Middle Persian

Tags: reference-request, transcription, persian

Is there any program or website that is able to transcribe Old and Middle Persian text (or transliteration of them) to an orthographic or phonetic transcription?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://parsi.wiki/dehkhodaworddetail-08b73cdcf25247689c183b1eaeec389f-fa.html) in Parsi.wiki website you can see transcribtion for specifically Old Persian, and for Middle Persian, just choose one of "Dekhoda=دهخدا or Moien= معین" dictionaries.